# Vue.js 2 can get body scroll position but not set body scroll position

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app where I am opening a modal and need to set the body under it to a fixed position to prevent it scrolling on mobile. This of course scrolls it to the top. Before opening the modal, I get the scroll position and set it like so:

```
this.bposition = document.body.scrollTop
console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
```

And this works fine, I can output the correct position in my console. But then, when I close my modal, I try to do this:

```
  console.log(this.bposition) // proves my close function is running and gets the correct value
  var el = document.querySelector('body')
  el.scrollLeft = 0 // have tried with and without this line
  el.scrollTop = this.bposition
```

But to no avail, the page will not scroll. I have tried on various elements within the page as well, none of them scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UGH. I found the solution. Apparently, even though the class that was making my body fixed was being removed when the modal was closed, it was not being removed fast enough. I solved this by introducing a timeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        el.scrollTop = this.bposition
      }, 500)
```

UPDATE:
Somewhat faster, I found the function (in external code) that removes the class and duplicated it before my call, which works even better:

```
  var el = document.querySelector('body')
  el.classList.remove('with-modal')
  el.scrollTop = this.bposition
```